# Append object to array if not exists elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have the following code

```
body: {
    script: {
        source: 'ctx._source.permissions.add(params.permission);',
        params: {
            permission
        }
    }
}
```

Permission object is an object being appended to array of permissions.
Permission object will have some id property. So permission object would be something like:

```
{
  id: 'some unique value',
  name: 'permission name
}
```

How do I only add it, if there is no permission object in that array with the property id, so If that array has an object with the params.id value I am trying to add, the add should fail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Below `source` :

```
"source":"List perm=ctx._source.permissions; if(perm!=null && !perm.stream().anyMatch(p-> p.id.equals(params.permission.id))){ctx._source.permissions.add(params.permission)}
```

I would advice you go through [painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html) document.

Comment: I believe I am using only update..single doc needs to be updated only... I'll mark it as answered anyways. Thank you a lot!